# Gesture on a UIView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, paint, user-interaction

I'm drawing on a `UIView` called `paintingView` and I can drag some imageview on it from a scrollview;
but I don't drag these objects directly on paintingView but in a `UIView` over it called "over".
This "over" has `userinteractionenabled = NO`, so in this way I can draw without problems.

Here is my problem: To leave these object from "over" I should add some gesture (a double tap or a longpress); but this "over" has `userinteractionenabled = NO` so gestures don't work
Do you have any idea how to add gesture to these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a subclass of UIView for your "over" view and overwrite `hitTest:withEvent:`.

If you have a touch on a dragged-in view, handle it (return the dragged-in view), otherwise return `[super hitTest:withEvent:];`.

(And turn `userInteractionEnabled` on again).

Answer (score 0):

Or another idea:

Put an `UITapGestureRecognizer` with minimumTouches: of two onto your paintingView and check, if the touch is within a dragged-in view. If so handle it here. But you probably draw accidentially with that approach.

You could also recognize the double-tap on your own. You probably already did overwrite `touchesBegan:` etc. You could recognize it there, go through the subviews of your "over" view and check, if it was in the bounds of an image. If so handle it and don't draw for that touch.